# Design an algorithm to minimize the total cost of all vertices, given some constraints.?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree

I couldnt get my head around this question, need help just a direction would be great..

Let there be a rooted directed tree T, not necessarily binary.

There is a weight associated with each vertex, such that the weight of a vertex is greater than the weight of the vertex's parent.

Each vertex can be designated as either a regular or a pivot vertex.

The cost of a pivot vertex is the same as its weight.

Regular vertices get discounts: their cost is their weight minus the weight of the closest ancestor that is a pivot vertex.

Thus, selecting a vertex as a pivot vertex may increase its cost, but it will decrease the costs of some of its descendants.

If a regular vertex has no ancestor which is a pivot vertex, then its cost is its weight itself. There is no limit on the number of pivot vertices.

I have to design an efficient algorithm to designate every vertex as either a regular vertex or a pivot vertex, such that the total cost of all vertices is minimized.

Comment: What is the discount for a vertex if it has two or more pivot ancestors that are located at the same distance from it?

Comment: How many vertices you have? Is this homework? Do you have a performance goal in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another dynamic program. I'm going to assume that the root must be a pivot node. For each node `u`, let `W[u]` be the weight of `u`. For nodes `u` and `v` such that `u = v` or `u` is a proper descendant of `v`, let `C[u, v]` be the optimum cost of the subtree rooted at `u` given that `u`'s leafmost pivot ancestor is `v`. Then we have a recurrence

```
C[u, u] = W[u] + sum over children t of u of C[t, u];
C[u, v] | u is a proper descendant of v
    = (W[u] - W[v]) + sum over children t of u of min(C[t, t], C[t, v]).
```

There is no separate base case because the sum may be empty. The running time is O(number of descendant-ancestor pairs), which is O(n^2).

Comment: Nice! Does the increasing weight of vertices help in any way?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I don't have any idea how to exploit that. I will note that, if a vertex has weight less than one of its ancestors, then there's no point in choosing that vertex as a pivot.

Answer (score 3):

You could use dynamic programming where DP[i,k] represents the smallest cost of the subtree rooted at vertex i assuming that looking into the subtree we can see k regular vertices (the concept is that pivot nodes are opaque, while regular nodes are transparent).

When working out the cost we use the normal logic everywhere except these k regular vertices.  For the k vertices we assign the cost of the vertex, but have not yet applied the discount.

The point is that when we assign a pivot node above this subtree of weight x, we can instantly calculate the final cost of the subtree by applying k times the discount x.

It is not clear whether this is efficient enough for your case because you have not said how large your graph is.

There will be O(n^2) entries in the dynamic programming table (where n is the number of vertices).
I would expect the recurrence relation to take O(n) to compute, so this will give an overall complexity of O(n^3).